# Autowire JUnit rule in integration test

Tags: spring, junit, autowired, spring-test, junit-rule

I have a piece of code which will be repeated across multiple integration tests. The code will run before and after tests. I have decided that using an JUnit `@Rule` would be the best way to achieve this.

The problem is that the rule will need to have access to few `@Autowired` Spring beans. (The tests are run with Spring Integration Test Runner so Autowire works fine.

I have a rule:

```java
public class CustomSpringRule extends ExternalResource {
    private final SomeOtherBean someOtherBean;

    public CustomSpringRule(SomeOtherBean someOtherBean) {
        this.someOtherBean = someOtherBean;
    }

    @Override
    public void before() {
        someOtherBean.someMethod();
    }

    // ...
}
```

I have my context to which I have added my bean:

```java
@Bean 
public CustomSpringRule getCustomSpringRule(SomeOtherBean someOtherBean) {
   return new CustomSpringRule(someOtherBean);
}
```

Finally I have just autowired the rule bean within test file:

```java
@Autowire
@Rule
public CustomSpringRule customSpringRule;
```

It all works fine but I never really used the `@Rule` annotation and I am slightly concerned that JUnit reflection and Spring Autowire won't go well together or there will be some issues that are not obvious at first look.

Does anyone have any suggestions whether this is valid and safe?

Comment: it seems like a bit of a code smell to have tests that need to be ran in a certain order.  Tests should be independent of each other

Comment: @Robbo_UK The OP does not say anything about running tests is a certain order.

Answer (score 1):

Using auto-wired rules is fine – there are no problems or limitations with this approach.

Note: I you are using component scanning (which is e.g. enabled in `@SpringBootTest`), you can simplify the rule implementation like this:

```
@Component
public class CustomSpringRule extends ExternalResource {
    @Autowired
    private SomeOtherBean someOtherBean;

    @Override
    public void before() {
        someOtherBean.someMethod();
    }

    // ...
}
```

Answer (score -2):

I don't think you need @Rule here,

> "I have a piece of code which will be repeated across multiple
>   integration tests. The code will run before and after tests."

This can be achieved using JUnit's @Before and @After annotations. Methods annotated with these annotations will execute before/after every test. So you can call your common code from these methods.

Comment: Yes I could although I wanted to avoid code repetition and have a tidy rule. On the other side I'm not sure whether I should use spring beans to do some testign logic.

Comment: well I mean keep your common code somewhere else than test so that you can use it from all tests. Only call to it will get repeated, something like you mentioned above "someOtherBean.someMethod();"